# Doctrine MongoDB: Embeded documents will not be saved if hydrating data into main document

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-odm

im using the hydrate function of the document manager (zend framework 2 application) for hydrating array data into a document.
Unfortunately embeded sub documents will not be updated in the databse (but main document will do).

Hydrating of the data is correct, but changes of the sub documents are not "noticed" by Unit-Of-Work.

Example:

**Request 1... (creating the document)**

```
$user = new Document\User();
$user->setName('administrator');

$address = new Document\UserAddress();
$address->setCity('cologne');
$user->setAddress($address);

// will insert new document correctly
$documentManager->persist($user);
$documentManager->flush();
```

**Request 2... (updating existing document)**

```
$repository = $this->documentManager->getRepository('Document\User');

$user = $repository->findOneBy(
    array('name' => 'administrator')
);

$documentManager->getHydratorFactory()->hydrate(
    $user,
    array(
        'name' => 'administrator',
        'address' => array(
            'city' => 'bonn' // change "cologne" to "bonn" 
        )
)
// note: "address" array will be correctly hydrated to a "UserAddress" document


// this will update the "User" document, but not the embedded "UserAddress" document
$documentManager->persist($user);
$documentManager->flush();
```

For me a little bit strange, but detaching the sub-document will cause an update

```
// after detaching sub object the documents will be saved correctly
// (but this cant be   the way it should be...?)
$documentManager->detach($user->getUserAddress());
$documentManager->persist($user);
$documentManager->flush();
```

Here are the annotations:

```
/*
 * @ODM\Document(collection="Users")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ODM\EmbedOne(targetDocument="Document\UserAddress")
     */
    protected $address;

    //... 

/*
 * @ODM\EmbeddedDocument()
 */
class UserAddress
{
    /**
     * @ODM\String
     */
    protected $city; 

    // ...
```

What do i wrong? Or is this a bug? Or...is the hydrate function not for "external" use?
Hope someone can help me

Regards
Norman